# Pagination for multiple loops in different div

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a big question. Whether it is possible to use a pagination for two loops. My code is,

```
<div class="first_div">
    <?php
        if (have_posts()) :
            $count = 0; 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                $count++;
                if ($count == 1) :
                    the_title();
                elseif ($count == 2) :
                    the_title();
                elseif ($count == 3) :
                    the_title();
                endif;
            endwhile;
        endif;      
    ?>
</div>

<div class="second_div">
    <h3>Div between first_div and third_div</h3>
</div>

<div class="third_div">
    <?php
        query_posts( array('posts_per_page'=>4,'offset'=>3) );
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
```

From the above code, i need to display totally 7 latest news. 3 in first_div and remaining 4 in third_div. And it works great. So, now what i need to do is, i need a pagination after that third_div. But actually i need a div inbetween first_div and third_div. So i could not able to create pagination after the third_div. Whether it is possible to give a pagination

Comment: Do you need to paginate just the first three posts or all 7 of the posts.

Comment: All the 7 posts @PieterGoosen

Comment: Then you can do all of this in **one** query. BTW, never ever use `query_posts`. It is prone to fail, specially with pagination

Comment: oh shit.. tk bro and thanks for your reply @pieter Goosen

Comment: Just for info purposes, take a [tour] and get to know how the site operates. If you need any help regarding the site, see [help]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in a comment above, this can all be done in one query.

Just an important note before I jump into the thick of things, never use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

(*CAVEAT: This is untested, but should work*)

OK, here is how we are going to do this

- Run your loop as normal. We are going to use the build in loop counter (`$current_post` and remember, it starts at `0`, not `1`) to count our posts and then according to this, do something
- On our first run, we are going to skip posts 4 - 7 and just display the first three in div 1
- After the first run of the loop, we are going to display the pagination in div 2
- To show posts 4  -7, we need to rewind our loop, and run it for the second time
- On this second run, we are going to skip the first three posts, and only show post 4 - 7 in div 3

Now, let get coding

1.) Run the loop as normal and exclude/skip posts 4 - 7

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 

        if( 0 === $wp_query->current_post ) {
            echo '<div class="first_div">'; // Open our div container only if it is the first post
        }

        the_title();

        if ( 2 === $wp_query->current_post ) {
            echo '</div>'; // Close our div container after post three
        }

        if( 3 >= $wp_query->current_post ) {
            //finish of the loop but displays nothing from posts 4 - 7
        }

    }
}
```

2.) Add our pagination as per normal

```
<div class="second_div">
    <h3>Div between first_div and third_div</h3>
</div>
```

3.) Rewind the loop so we can rerun it

```
rewind_posts();
```

4.) Rerun the loop and only display posts 4 - 7

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 

        if( 2 <= $wp_query->current_post ) {
            //Skip posts 4 - 7 and displays nothing
        }

        if( 3 === $wp_query->current_post ) {
            echo '<div class="third_div">'; // Open our div container only if it is the fourth post
        }

        the_title();

        if ( 6 === $wp_query->current_post ) {
            echo '</div>'; // Close our div container after post seven
        }

    }
}
```

That should it